React do some work after dispatch store method in fulfilled reducer state
I have a dispatch method like this:
dispatch(fetchData(...)).then(() => {
  // do some work after fulfilled
})

and in store I have this methods:
// ** Fetch Invoices
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk(
  'appInvoice/fetchData',
  async (params: DataParams) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      baseURL + `Invoice/${params.id}?sortBy=id&isSortAscending=false`,
      { params }
    )

    return response.data
  }
)

and in my reducer:
builder.addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.data = action.payload.items
  state.total = action.payload.totalItems
  state.loading = false
})

I want do some work after dispatch fulfilled reducer. How can do this?

fetchData is a Redux-Toolkit Thunk action, so you have a couple ways to execute additional logic after the Thunk action is fulfilled. Firstly though you need to understand that all Thunk actions resolve, so to find out if the action was fulfilled or rejected you should unwrap the returned Promise. See Handling Thunk Results for specific details.

Using the Promise Chain
const callback = () => {
  dispatch(fetchData(...)).unwrap()
    .then((data) => {
      // do some work after fulfilled
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // catch error/rejections and handle/ignore
    });
};


Converting to async/await and try/catch
const callback = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await dispatch(fetchData(...)).unwrap();
    // do some work after fulfilled
  } catch(error) {
    // catch error/rejections and handle/ignore
  };
};



